# Facebook bot stopped working after password reset

Tags: bots, botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a few facebook bots created using Bot Framework, C# and running on Azure.

All of them stopped working at the same time after I went to facebook, changed password and clicked "Log Out All Sessions" under Security.

That's the error message that I can see in the Bot Framework website:

```
{"error":
  {"message":"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user changed their password or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.",
  "type":"OAuthException",
  "code":190,
  "error_subcode":460,
  "fbtrace_id":"Hh+N0op30L5"}}
```

I tried regenerating page access token and replacing it in the Bot Framework setting. I tried resubscribing the bot to the Facebook page. I still can't get the bot to work again.

Comment: I could get the bots to work again by a combination of re-generating the page access token and re-registering the webhooks. Neither action works immediately, and neither action works by itself.

Comment: You continue to receive the same error after re-generating the access token, or does the call just not work?

Comment: I mean I fixed it somehow. So regenerating the token and copying it into the bot framework's settings didn't work on its own. Re-adding webhooks didn't work by itself either. But somehow, perhaps after a few minutes wait, the bots came back to life. So I couldn't really figure out the exact sequence of actions that allowed me to do it.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, you just need to regenerate the access token then verify and save that Facebook can access your webhook.

You do this from the Edit Subscription section of Webhook.

Comment: But won't regenerating the access token affect the app side? What does a user logging out or changing a password have to do with it?